# Como quebrar linhas de acordo com um valor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular-5

Como faço para quebrar linhas de acordo com o valor ? Por exemplo 
a = 8. Ai eu tenho uma variável "d" q recebe uma string. var d = "obra escrita considerada na sua redação original". Se eu colocar um If = a; ela percorre a string contando sempre q for 8 caracteres ela quebra a linha. Quem poder me ajudar agradeço, já tentei algumas ideias mas não tive sucesso.

Comment: Mas o `b` e o `c` fazem o que ?

Comment: @Isac Tentei simplificar a minha pergunta, estava meio confusa mesmo. A ideia é ....Eu tenho uma string e quero fazer quebra de linha sempre q chegar no oitavo carácter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode solucionar esse problema com uma expressão regular simples na forma de:

```
/.{1,8}/g
```

Explicação:

```
/     - Inicio da expressão regular
.     - Qualquer caratere
{1,8} - Entre 1 a 8 vezes, sempre apanhando o máximo possível.
/     - Fim da expressão regular
g     - Aplicado globalmente na string
```

Se este numero nunca muda pode simplificar e utilizar diretamente na função [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) que lhe devolve um array como resultado:

```js
let texto = "obra escrita considerada na sua redação original";
let blocosTexto = texto.match(/.{1,8}/g);
let textoQuebrado = blocosTexto.join("\n");

console.log(textoQuebrado);
```

Como o valor obtido é um array, para construir um texto com quebras de linha para cada valor do array basta utilizar o método [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) de array passando o `\n` com parâmetro. Se por acaso o resultado for para mostrar em html então deve utilizar `"<br>"` no `join` para ter as quebras de linhas apropriadas.

Se o valor que indica a quantidade de careteres para quebrar poder mudar, ou se for lido/construido com base no *input* do usuário então já precisa de utilizar [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) para construir a expressão regular:

```js
let texto = "obra escrita considerada na sua redação original";
let quebra = 8;
let regex = new RegExp(`.{1,${quebra}}`, 'g');
let blocosTexto = texto.match(regex);
let textoQuebrado = blocosTexto.join("\n");

console.log(textoQuebrado);
```

Comment: muitoooo obrigadoooo....Vou ler e etestar o q vc escreveu. Valeu mesmo cara.